# Зачем нужна сетка?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу понять зачем нужны модульные сетки при верстке. Видел гору заявлений что сетка позволяет верстать гораздо быстрее, адаптив делать с ней раз плюнуть да и вообще она почему то у всех на слуху и многие как мне показалось вообще считают что без нее адаптивный дизайн не сделать. Может я чего то не понимаю но для меня возиться с этими колонками, позиционировать элементы в них, расставлять классы-брэкпойнты, засорять html является дополнительными трудностями. Допустим человек хочет сделать три карточки чтобы на lg они были 3-в ряд, на md 2-в ряд и одна на новой строке, а на sm все в колонку. Я не думаю что сложней расстановки классов bootstrap элементам просто задать контейнеру `flex-wrap` и элементам в медиа запросе lg(33%,33%,33%) md(50%,50%,100%) sm(100%,100%,100%). Смотрел стрим https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQIh8SBXc5c&index=30&list=PLQ2eyErB1Ejz9GWDzFbp15k7RjzmWf8qm и там автор элементы navbar'а так же обертывал в колонки. Вновь вопрос зачем это делать если можно было просто блоки лого и меню раскидать в левую и правую часть контейнера?
В общем то был бы неописуемо благодарен если бы разъяснили всю мощь сеток.

Comment: не сложней, но тебе потребуется больше времени, логичнее накидать сетку использую тот же бутстрап, где ты можешь просто прописать классы и тебе легче будет делать адаптив под все экраны

Comment: Так сложилось, что молодые фронты в большинстве не умеют верстать и понятие pixel perfect сменилось на верстка по сетке. Это стандарт и в крупных компаниях команде проще понимать код. Тоже самое и бэм. Но я, как и вы, считаю это деградацией

Comment: Поведение сетки может быть разным. Например на phone текст нужно выровнять по центру и лучше это сделать именно на уровне одной ячейки. Так что здесь всё очень сильно зависит от задачи.